# pyspark check element in a huge list

Tags: pyspark

I have a spark dataframe of moderate size (like 10000 to 100000 rows), and would like to filter rows based on whether they are in a huge list (tens of millions in length). What I did was like:

```
sc.broadcast(huge_list)
df = df.filter(df['some_col'].isin(huge_list))
```

however, the performance was rather slow. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just perform a `join`.
You explode your list in lines. Then, you join the two dataframes with `inner`. The result should be faster.

Comment: Yes it worked but I don't completely understand. When I execute my original code, the pyspark shell just stuck forever. When I used join, at least the stage bar appeared and began to progress. Doesn't join involve a lot of network shuffling while isin happens at a local level? Why is join faster?

Comment: @YuchenHu Basically, if you `broadcast` you huge list, it will be copied on each and every worker node. Therefore, just this step is requesting too many ressources and your process is stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Steven's above comment might be not feasible if second table is hard to fit into memory, the reason why you think your job is stuck because Catalyst optimizer creates OR statements and chains them one by one, you can disable Catalyst for pushdown predicate optimization.